# Stash not working while inside exp channel

Tags: stash, channel

I have used exp stash to get entry ids. But the code is not working inside exp:channel
My code:

```
{exp:stash:set name="recently_viewed_ids" output="no" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" } 
  {exp:channel:entries channel="blog"  sort="desc"   disable="pagination" entry_id="not 26|25" }
    {entry_id}|
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Result:

`{exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids'}{/exp:stash:get}` ---- working fine

`{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"  sort="desc"  entry_id="not {exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids'}{/exp:stash:get}" }{entry_id}{/exp:channel:entries}`
--- not working

Can anyone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with injecting stash pipe separated entry_ids into channel entries loop when no results](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/6570/problem-with-injecting-stash-pipe-separated-entry-ids-into-channel-entries-loop) OR [Stashing a structure variable and using it as a channel parameter](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/stashing-a-structure-variable-and-using-it-as-a-channel-parameter)

Comment: See the first link above, it'll answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked. But one more question. Can I set the entry ids to the same stash name multiple times? ie, at one exp channel call , i will call exp:stash:set name='x' . Again I want the entry ids append to the same 'x' with another exp:channel call. Is it possible? It seems its not working if we call exp:stash:set again . Please help.

Comment: Post a new question to keep things separate. First search to see if there's already an answer out there.

Comment: Posted as new question with sample code(http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15403/call-exp-stack-multiple-time-through-multiple-exp-channel-call)