# Call exp stash multiple times through multiple exp channel calls

Tags: stash, channel

Can I set the entry ids to the same stash name multiple times?
 ie, at one exp channel call , i will call `exp:stash:set name='x'`. 
Again I want the entry ids append to the same 'x' with another `exp:channel:entries` call. Is it possible?

It seems it's not working if we call `exp:stash:set` again.

My code:

```
{exp:stash:set  name="recently_viewed_ids" replace="yes" output="no" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" append="yes"  }
  {exp:channel:entries channel="blog"  dynamic="no" backspace="1"  entry_id="not 26|24"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set }

{exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids'}{/exp:stash:get}
```

Outputs `23|22`

```
{exp:stash:append name="recently_viewed_ids"  }
  {exp:channel:entries channel="business"  dynamic="no" backspace="1"  entry_id="8"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:append }

{exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids'}{/exp:stash:get}
```

Outputs `23|22`

Please help

Answer (score 2):

The reason your output on the second get is the same is because of parse order. If you set that get to run later with process="end" it should show the combined result:

```
{exp:stash:set
    name="recently_viewed_ids" 
    parse_tags="yes" 
    trim="yes" 
}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

Result 1: {exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids'}

<hr>

{exp:stash:append 
    name="recently_viewed_ids"  
    parse_tags="yes"
    trim="yes"
}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="business" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:append}

Result 2: {exp:stash:get name='recently_viewed_ids' process='end'}
```

Also, the first set doesn't need to be an append, and the second set needed a parse_tags parameter. The get also only needs a single tag not a tag pair, because it isn't set as a stash list.

---

UPDATE:
Setting the ids as a list:

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="recently_viewed_ids"
    parse_tags="yes" 
}
    {stash:ids_1}{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_1" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}{/stash:ids_1}
    {stash:ids_2}{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_2" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}{/stash:ids_2}
    {stash:ids_3}{exp:channel:entries channel="CHANNEL_3" dynamic="no" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:channel:entries}{/stash:ids_3}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

Result 1: {exp:stash:get_list name='recently_viewed_ids'}{ids_1}{/exp:stash:get_list}
<hr>
Result 2: {exp:stash:get_list name='recently_viewed_ids'}{ids_2}{/exp:stash:get_list}
<hr>
Result 3: {exp:stash:get_list name='recently_viewed_ids'}{ids_3}{/exp:stash:get_list}
<hr>
Result 1+2: {exp:stash:get_list name='recently_viewed_ids'}{ids_1}|{ids_2}{/exp:stash:get_list}
<hr>
Result 1+2+3: {exp:stash:get_list name='recently_viewed_ids'}{ids_1}|{ids_2}|{ids_3}{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cant give process="end" since I had to call exp:stash 3 or more times.Hope  Process end will return only the final data. But I want all intermediate values. Can you please help how I can retrieve all intermediate values?

Comment: I'm not too sure of your overall purpose on the template you're working on, so just trying to answer the question as presented. But setting stash variables in a list might suit your needs better and give you more control over the combined ids, please see the updated example.